# Follow button not working

Tags: follow

In internal Salesforce, I click on the Follow button.  It immediately changes to Following  but then quickly changes back to Follow.  I started noticing this a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was caused by the fact that I was following 1,118 records.  Once I deleted entries from the entity subscription object, I was able to follow records.